# problem with extending classes

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm making Braid. I have a class `Wall` that prevents that an object goes into a wall.
Everything with `Wall` is working. But now I'm trying to make the same with the ceilings.
My ceiling class extends `Wall`. I've simply made a constructor like this:

```
public Ceiling(boolean deadly, int[] xPositions, int[] yPositions)
{
     super(deadly,
     Direction.Down, //Enum: the direction you have to leave the wall (Left, Right)
                     //Here of course down
     xPositions, yPositions);
}
```

Now I have in my level-class an `ArrayList` of all the Walls and an `ArrayList` of all the Ceilings.
I have to add the Walls on this way:

```
walls.add(new Wall(false, Direction.Right, ..., ...));
```

And the Ceilings on this way:

```
ceilings.add(new Ceiling(false, ..., ...));
```

The `...` replaces the coordinates.

If I check if there is an object in a Ceiling: there has nothing happened: the object goes through the ceiling. And if I use this way to add a Ceiling, it works:

```
ceilings.add(new Wall(false, Direction.Down, ..., ...));
```

I hope I've explained well.
Does somebody know what the problem is??

Thanks

**Edit:**

This is my collition code:

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r)
{
    if (!bounds.intersects(r))
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < yPositions.length; i++) {
        Line l = new Line(xPositions[i - 1], yPositions[i - 1], xPositions[i], yPositions[i]);
        if (r.intersectsLine(l)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**My Code**

---

'`doodelijk`' means deadly

Wall:

```
package levels;

import domein.Direction;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Wall
{

    public boolean doodelijk;
    public int[] yPositions;
    public int[] xPositions;
    private Rectangle bounds;
    public Direction directionToLeave;

    public Wall(boolean doodelijk, Direction directionToLeave, int[] yPositions, int[] xPositions)
    {
        this.doodelijk = doodelijk;
        this.yPositions = yPositions;
        this.xPositions = xPositions;
        this.directionToLeave = directionToLeave;
        createRectangle();
    }

    public boolean intersects(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (!bounds.intersects(r))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < yPositions.length; i++) {
            Line l = new Line(xPositions[i - 1], yPositions[i - 1], xPositions[i], yPositions[i]);
            if (r.intersectsLine(l)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void createRectangle()
    {
        int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int y = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++)
        {
            int tx = xPositions[i];
            int ty = yPositions[i];
            if (x > tx)
            {
                x = tx;
            }
            if (y > ty)
            {
                y = ty;
            }
            if (x1 < tx)
            {
                x1 = tx;
            }
            if (y1 < ty)
            {
                y1 = ty;
            }
        }
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, x1 - x + 1, y1 - y +1);
        System.out.println("Rect: " + bounds);
    }

    class Line extends Line2D
    {

        Point2D p1;
        Point2D p2;

        public Line()
        {
            p1 = new Point();
            p2 = new Point();
        }

        public Line(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
        {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }

        public Line(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2)
        {
            this();
            setLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
        }

        @Override
        public double getX1()
        {
            return p1.getX();
        }

        @Override
        public double getY1()
        {
            return p1.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public Point2D getP1()
        {
            return p1;
        }

        @Override
        public double getX2()
        {
            return p2.getX();
        }

        @Override
        public double getY2()
        {
            return p2.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public Point2D getP2()
        {
            return p2;
        }

        @Override
        public void setLine(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2)
        {
            p1.setLocation(X1, Y1);
            p2.setLocation(X2, Y2);
        }

        public Rectangle2D getBounds2D()
        {
            return new Rectangle((int) getX1(), (int) getY1(), (int) (getX2() - getX1()), (int) (getX2() - getY1()));
        }
    }

    public void setXpositions(int ... xPos)
    {
        this.xPositions = xPos;
    }

    public void setYpositions(int ... yPos)
    {
        this.yPositions = yPos;
    }

    public void setPositions(int[] yPos, int[] xPos)
    {
        setXpositions(xPos);
        setYpositions(yPos);
    }
}
```

Ceiling:

```
package levels;

import domein.Direction;


public class Ceiling extends Wall
{
    public Ceiling(boolean doodelijk, int[] xPositions, int[] yPositions)
    {
        super(doodelijk, Direction.Down, yPositions, xPositions);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making Braid? Last I checked Braid was already made and released. I can't find any reference to you making Braid?

Comment: Err, what actually is the problem?

Comment: So what is exactly your question; how to call the superclass constructor in class Ceiling? Without seeing the rest of your code, it's very difficult to tell you what's wrong. Run the code in an IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans for example) and use the debugger to step through the code, to follow line by line what happens when the program runs.

Comment: The only error I see is:
(int) (getX2() - getY1())
for height, that should be Y2 I guess

Comment: Thank you. I correct it but the problem isn't gone. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure about your settings of the xposition and yposition arguments?   That is, is the ceiling really where you think it is?  Is it the same in your two variants of the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the code that checks for the "collision". I cant see any problem in the one you've given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems with your classes. There might be a bug somewhere else and you would have to post the complete classes for us to identify it.

Comment: Now my problem is I am a Begian and speaks Dutch and I am 13 years old. If a have to translate all my comments, names, ....